# Visual Studio terminal is blocked by black box

Tags: terminal

I have this issue on my visual studio terminal where it is just blocked by black boxes, no matter if i restart it, delete visual studio it doesn't work, I do not understand why. I believe it happened when i tried to install a react library and then i cancelled it, since then it has been like this.

[Here is a image of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVQ9H.png)

I tired deleting it, restarting it, etc. it has been like this for some time.

Comment: I have managed to fix it, If anyone has this issue, Go to your settings.json file in vscode and add this line to temporarilt fix it ( "terminal.integrated.enableImages": false, ) .